# Searching for storage space for music file

Tags: ios, api, ionic3

I am building an app for a music band. The songs of the bands are not available in any website or any social media. They have sent me the mp3 files via mail. Is there any platform where I can upload the musics and Fetch them to my app via API ? Please help.

Development platform : IONIC 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use any cloud storage service that offers access via HTTP(S). I'd suggest you store sensitive login data in a local database that is fetched in the background on every external access, or, even better (if supported by the hosting service), as a private key file.

You could also rent a server for a few bucks and use it as a file host. All data associated with a particular band can then be stored in public folders accessible via HTTP with randomly generated uuids as folder names (used as keys).

Hope I could help! Good luck!

Cheers
Mike